# How To get all the session values stores at the server using php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to use session values in my script which are stored at the server using php can any one kindly explain the process to achieve this.

I want to build a chat app for this am planning to use those session values.

Assume usera and userb are logged in and their userid is sessioned based on this scenario i want to do a chat app.

Now i had done the app but i had used setinterval function of Javascript and am calling the chats i want to avoid the database hits on every 3 mill sec.

Kindly Help me out

Thanks In Advance

Comment: I'm confused, what is it you want us to answer? How to use $_SESSION?

Comment: No i want to get all the sessions which are set.

Comment: Let me explain, usera is logged from sys1 and userb logged from sys2 now i want to write a script which will gives the all sessions which are from this domain

Comment: Can you use Memcached or Redis instead? Sounds like you're attempting to use session files as a file cache.

Comment: Scenario is two persons usera and usreb are chatting usera had entered chat and clicked submit i want to show this msg immediately to the userb. without hitting to the db how can i achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You're basically attempting to use PHP session files as a file cache.

Instead, you should use an object caching system such as Memcached or Redis. If memory caching isn't an option (shared hosting, etc), then you could implement your own file cache (or you could use something like [PHPFastCache](https://github.com/khoaofgod/phpfastcache), which supports file caching).

Note: File caching for a chat app may or may not speed up your application. It depends on how you implement it and a number of other factors.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi put the session value in input box,

    <input type='hidden' id='session_value' value='<?php $_SESSION['value']?>'>

Using the id fetch the session value in script,

 <script>
var session_value = document.getElementById ( "session_value" );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

3ms is insanely short delay to run a polling chat system. I suggest increasing it to at least 200ms but preferably around 1000ms.

$_SESSION values are per user and not recommended for viewing a chat stream for a number of reasons. Instead it sounds like you are looking more to just update the chat feed.

The database unless it is hosted on another server and $_SESSION will be the equivalent, since the database is effectively files as well. The database will actually generally be faster than reading raw file storage since Queries are normally cached and Indexing helps lookup records quicker. In addition you won't have to worry about concurrent connections to the files either.

If anything enable OPCache and install APCu for your PHP installation, to help aid the serving of requests. OPCache will cache your compiled OP code into memory so that subsequent requests to the file won't need to be recompiled.
APCu will act as your file cache, again storing your rendered data in memory.
Additionally many Database Frameworks such as Doctrine can also utilize APC caching for query and result caching.

Instead of using a InnoDB or MyISAM storage engines for your chat messages I suggest trying the MEMORY storage engine.
So instead of accessing the File System I/O your database would instead be utilizing the Memory I/O. The general concept is few writes, many reads. Since one person writes to the database, requires everyone to read the data. Just keep in mind that the Memory storage engine is temporary and is lost if the server restarts or power is lost.

For more information see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/memory-storage-engine.html

Overall if you are able, I would suggest look at using Socket IO (Websockets) instead of either database or file based caching. This puts the load on the clients instead of the server, and everything occurs in real-time instead of polling for changes.

For some examples see:

1. Ratchet http://socketo.me/
2. React http://reactphp.org/
3. Node.js http://tutorialzine.com/2014/03/nodejs-private-webchat/